# How to correctly deploy Angular app to AWS AppRunner?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my Angular app to AWS AppRunner, I have tried a couple of ways, unfortunately the AWS documentation is not clear enough, for me at least.

I will explain step by step what I did.

1. Created new AppRunner service from GitHub repo
2. Selected runtime Nodejs 18

---

3.a For "Build command" I have tried initially with "npm install"

**Result** with above build command is:

- App is build completely and deployed successfully
- Accessing the AWS app link results in "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/myapp/assets/index.html'"

---

3.b I taught that I needed the build command of the Angular app in the "Build command", therefore the "Build command" became: "npm install && ng build"

**Result** with above build command is:

- The ng command returned a non-zero code: 127

---

3.c I have tried to add to the build command the angular/cli to have access to ng command. The "Build command" became: "npm install -g @angular/cli && npm install && ng build"

**Result** is the same as above, code 127

---

Is there a link to the documentation that I can use ? or please help you have more experience and would like to share.